# Swift UITextField inputView with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set a tableView to fill a UITextField via .inputView method. And actually, it's not working at all.. I don't know what I've missed...

Here is the test code I wrote, it works fine with UIPickerView but does not show anything with UITableView.. thanks for your support !

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var itemPicker = UIPickerView()
    var playerTableView = UITableView()

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldOne: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTwo: UITextField!
    
    
    var firstTextField = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    var secondTextField = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFieldOne.delegate = self
        textFieldTwo.delegate = self
        itemPicker.delegate = self
        itemPicker.dataSource = self
        playerTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "playerCell")
        playerTableView.delegate = self
        playerTableView.dataSource = self
        textFieldOne.inputView = itemPicker
        textFieldTwo.inputView = playerTableView
    }
    
    
    // PickerView
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return firstTextField.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return firstTextField[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textFieldOne.text = firstTextField[row]
    }
    
    // TableView
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return firstTextField.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = playerTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerCell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "playerCell")
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.text = firstTextField[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        textFieldTwo.text = firstTextField[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike a `UIPickerView`, a `UITableView` has no intrinsic content size. You need to give it a frame (or auto-layout constraints).

Comment: true you need to specify constraints for the UITextField which you can either do in storyboard or via Code